# MS Access VB: Boolean Function not working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a function returning boolean

```
Function frmName() as String
  frmName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
End Function

Function frmChck() As Boolean
  If Not IsNull(DLookup("RFid", "qryRestriction", "FormName =" & 
      frmName)) Then 
    frmChck = True
End Function
```

and adding this code on every form `on_open`

```
If frmChck = True then
  Cancel = True
End If
```

but still the form opens, though if I code it :

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("RFid", "qryRestriction", "FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'")) Then
```

on every form `on_open` the procedure works as it cancels the opening of the form

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second query works is because you're referencing the form name directly with the `Me` keyword instead of reading the name of the active form. A form doesn't become active until the `on_open` event is finished.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.open) for a description of the from open lifecycle:

> Open → Load → Resize → Activate → Current

Answer (score 0):

Field `FormName` is text, thus your function should read:

```vb
Function frmChck() As Boolean

    frmChck = Not IsNull(DLookup("RFid", "qryRestriction", "FormName = '" & frmName & "'")) 

End Function
```